# Почему useEffect вызывается несколько раз?

Tags: reactjs

Почему при щелчке мышью useEffect внутри документа срабатывает несколько раз?
А по щелчку на элементе списка еще больше?

https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-chatterjee-17x1e?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что при каждом срабатывании Эффекта происходит регистрация нового слушателя. И чем больше будет вызовов Эффекта, тем больше будет регистраций.

Добавьте `console.log("click", todos);` рядом с регистрацией слушателя и Вы увидите когда и сколько раз вызывается Эффект и что находится в todos

Comment: тот console.log, что я вставил внутрь useEffect, срабатывает каждый раз с новым массивом, но делает это один раз. Не могу понять, почему в одном щелчке это все накапливается

Comment: я же написал, что `document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);` при каждом вызове регистрирует новый обработчик, при этом старый обработчик никуда не девается

Comment: хорошо, а как можно решить этот вопрос? чтобы вызов был 1 раз

Comment: а с какой целью Вы регистрируете отслеживание клика?

Comment: я пытаюсь выяснить, почему например console.log не вызывается несколько раз, а только один, почему console.log не накапливается, и какой чертой обладает addEventListener и ему подобные, что накапливаются

Comment: Представьте что есть массив `clicks = []`. Каждый вызов `addEventListener('click', function)` добавляет в этот массив слушателя. После 5 вызовов мы получим `clicks = [function, function, function, function, function]`. И вот когда происходит клик, то вызываются поочереди все функции, которые присутствуют в массиве `clicks`